# Best method for adding items to a recyclerview from another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So i have a recyclerview in my MainActivity and want to open a window (new activity?) and add items to my recyclerview from that window. Right now i'm trying to do it like this. The problem is that when i add the item to the list, my recyclerview does not show it (i guess it's because i don't update my adapter?) what is the best way of doing this? I don't mind changing the structure of my program.

MainActivity.java

```
        static ArrayList<filterItem> filters = new ArrayList<>();

        filters.add(new filterItem("1", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        filters.add(new filterItem("2", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        filters.add(new filterItem("3", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        filters.add(new filterItem("4", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        filters.add(new filterItem("5", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        filters.add(new filterItem("6", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        filters.add(new filterItem("7", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        filters.add(new filterItem("8", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        filters.add(new filterItem("9", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        filters.add(new filterItem("10", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, filters);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

BrowseFilters.java
`MainActivity.filters.add(filterToAdd);`

I know there are already posts answering the question of how to do this, and the answers says just to make the list static as I have done. But is this the best way to do it or are there better ways of doing this? If making a static list is the best way, then how doi show my updated list in MainActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after add an item into adapter

Best practice in this case is `startActivityForResult()` from MainActivity

In the SecondActivity, pass the extra item you want to add in MainActivity back to MainActivity

In the MainActivity, override `onActivityResult()` and handle adding the extra item into the adapter and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`